# For loop creating an array with one less value than expected

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

I am sure this is something really simple but I have not been able to work out what is going on for a while now.

I have a List I get from shared preference:

```
// Access the shared preferences to see if the user has saved any alarms yet
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("AppData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String alarmsstring = sharedPreferences.getString("AlarmsStringSP", "None");

// Split the the main alarm string into array of strings values for alarm objects
    List<String> alarmObjectsArray = Arrays.asList(alarmsstring.split("\\s*;\\s*"));
```

I check the size of that list using:

```
System.out.println("Testing"+ alarmObjectsArray.size());
```

And I get:

```
I/System.out: Testing3
```

Which is what I expect so fine up to there.

I then create a new array list and put each element of the old list into the new one converted to an object.

Like this:

```
   // Iterate through the alarm objects, and place each item into the alarms array
    for (int i = 0; i < alarmObjectsArray.size()-1; i++){
        // For each of the alarm objects split them into their induvidual items so they can be
        // converted back to the correct type.
        List<String> alarmItems = Arrays.asList(alarmObjectsArray.get(i).split("\\s*,\\s*"));
        Alarm alarm = new Alarm(Integer.parseInt(alarmItems.get(0)),Integer.parseInt(alarmItems.get(1)),
                Boolean.parseBoolean(alarmItems.get(2)), Boolean.parseBoolean(alarmItems.get(3)),
                Boolean.parseBoolean(alarmItems.get(4)),Boolean.parseBoolean(alarmItems.get(5)),
                Boolean.parseBoolean(alarmItems.get(6)), Boolean.parseBoolean(alarmItems.get(7)),
                Boolean.parseBoolean(alarmItems.get(8)));
        alarms.add(alarm);
    }
```

The only thing is when it comes out of the for loop I check the new array size with:

```
System.out.println("Testing"+ alarms.size());
```

And I get:

```
I/System.out: Testing2
```

Somehow it has lost one when it was taken from the list into the array. I know there is a lot text in the for loop but I can't see any reason for having one less.

Comment: maybe because of `alarmObjectsArray.size()-1`?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < alarmObjectsArray.size(); i++)`

Comment: `alarmObjectsArray.size()-1` why used ?

Comment: Because an array starts at 0?

Comment: that code is fine 0..2 is fine

Comment: because of alarmObjectsArray.size()-1  : replace it with  for (int i = 0; i < alarmObjectsArray.size(); i++) .. i know one gets lil confused when using array.length and araylist.size()

Comment: Upvoted. This is well-written, has code, and the expected / actual output. Please don't downvote on grounds of obviousness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for (int i = 0; i < alarmObjectsArray.size(); ++i/*I'm an old-fashioned cat*/){` will index over *every* element in the array. (`i` will start at 0, and finish at and including a value one less than the size of the array).

Drop the -1 term.

For the avoidance of doubt, Java arrays are *zero-based*. Java ain't Fortran you know.

Finally, `< size()` is more idiomatic than the equivalent `<= size() - 1`. Futhermore `size() - 1` can yield sheer devilry in C++ if `size()` is an unsigned type - as it often is - and happens to be zero!

Comment: Yup. Arrays in Java are zero-based.

Comment: I am confused? The index is 0, 1, 2 and the array size is 3 the the for loop will go through 0, 1,2,3. Or am I missing somthing haha?

Comment: @ColdFire so can you explain why they are saying to remove the -1

Comment: You do understand the meaning of `<`? It will not "go up" to the array size.

Comment: @NicholasMuir you have to add = there or remove -1 that is what they are saying

Comment: < i undertood to be larger which means it goes up to array size, =< I understood to not go up to or above.

Comment: Rolled back the edit. I don't like making normal words like zero-based *look* like `code`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < alarmObjectsArray.size()-1; i++)
```

- `for` means that the code inside the loop is done until the condition is true.
- The first loop will run with `i = 0`, as you correctly set.
- Every loop will add 1 to `i` since you wrote `i++`.
- Your exit condition is `i < size-1`. Since `size = 3`, it means `i < 3-1`, equals to `i < 2`so the code will run for **i = 0 and i = 1**

This means the code will run only 2 times.

In for loop, if you want to avoid the `foreach`, use `i < size` or `i <= size-1`, otherwise you will lose an item.

Hope you understood the explaination.

Answer (score 1):

As I see you do not certainly understand the `for` loop, so let's focus on it.

```
int[] array = new int[5];
System.out.println(array.size());
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

The above code will print:

```
>5
>0
>1
>2
>3
>4
```

The array has 5 cells. The're `0-indexed` so the indexes start from `0`. It results in last cell having the index of `array.size() - 1`. So if you want to loop through all indexes you have to loop from `0` to `array.size()-1`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I see my error now. Cheers